# (Debian) Init script auto respawn?

Tags: service, init

I created a service script in /etc/init.d (Debian) that is working - I can start/stop/status/restart. But it is not respawning. Is it possible to respawn?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can respawn it by editing `/etc/inittab` file.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how to do this? Also maybe provide an example?

Comment: editing /etc/inittab can be done by issuing the command vim /etc/inittab. An example is already present at line 63.

Comment: Thanks I tried and it works perfectly. g1:2345:respawn:/path/to/myscript.sh